# WP_Query results stored in variables

Tags: wp-query

I'd like to know if there is a way to store WP_Query results in variables that I can then go ahead and insert anywhere on the page outside of the loop. For instance, say I want to get the feature image urls of three latest posts and I want to set variables in a way akin to the following.(note that the code below is for illustration purposes only as I have no idea how to parse the results from the loop for each post)

```
$featureImageFirst = wp_get_attachment_url();
$featureImageSecond = wp_get_attachment_url();
$featureImageThird = wp_get_attachment_url();
```

In response to Soren's help I did this:

Hi Soren, please have a look at my code. This is what is happening.

```
    <?php
    // Get latest three posts
    $args = [ 
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'orderby'      => 'date',
        'order'    => 'DESC'
    ];

    // Fetch posts
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() )
    {
        while ( $query->have_posts() )
        {
            $query->the_post(); 
            $featureImage[$current_post] = wp_get_attachment_url(     get_post_thumbnail_id() );
        }
    }
    ?>
<div><img src="<?php echo $featureImage[0]; ?>"></div>
```

And this is what I get

```
<div><img src></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Pieter - I wasn't aware of the etiquette until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read, you read the URL/path to the post thumbnails is an array. We need to look at a couple of things here to make this as lean and predictable as possible

### IMPORTANT CONSIDERATIONS

- We do need some way to make sure that we get the latest three posts which actually have thumbnails to avoid unexpected output and bugs. It is always important to code with a mindset that my code will be hacked and it will fail and it will have bugs. Once you have that mindset, then you look at your code from a different angle, which make you to ask questions like: *What if this specific poece of code returns an error, how will it affect my output, how will I handle such errors safely and reliable in an expected, predictable way without breaking something else on my site*
- We only really need the post ID's from the three latest posts, so to save resources, why not only query for post ID's
- When you need lean, non-paginated, to the point queries like this, I always use `get_posts` as it breaks pagination legally. This makes your query faster, which really helps on sites with many posts. You can still use `WP_Query`, but then you would need to remember to pass `'no_found_rows' => true` to your query arguments (*which is exactly what `get_posts` does btw*). Another plus using `get_posts` is that it just return the `$posts` property from the `WP_Query` instance. But this is all just personal preference

### THE CODE

I prefer to write functions for long pieces of code to keep my templates as simple and short as poosible. I can then just call my functions where I need them or even use `do_action()` calls in my templates and then hook my functions to that specific action

Anyway, lets look at the function; (***NOTE:*** The following is untested, needs PHP 5.4+ and canbe made more dynamic as needed)

```
function get_latest_post_thumbnails_urls()
{
    // Set an empty variable which will hold our array of URL's
    $output = [];

    // Set our query args
    $args = [
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's
        'meta_query'     => [ // Get posts which has thumbnails only
            [
                'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ]
        ],
        // Any additional parameters you might need
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // ALWAYS make sure we have posts, else return $output
    if ( !$q )
        return $output;

    // Ok, we have posts, lets loop through them and create an array of URL's
    foreach ( $q as $id ) 
        $output[] = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ) );

    // Return our array
    return $output;
}
```

We can now use `get_latest_post_thumbnails_urls();` anywhere where we need it.

### USAGE

We need to remember, our function might return an empty array, or an array with 1, 2, or 3 URL's, so we must always make sure about this before we try to use anything to avoid bugs and have unexpected failures

This is a probable safe usecase we can use

```
$urls = get_latest_post_thumbnails_urls();
// Make sure we do not have an empty array

if ( $urls ) {
    foreach ( $urls as $url ) {
        // Do something with your thumbnail url
        echo $url . '</br>'; // For testing, remove this
    }
}
```

Comment: Pieter I tested the code just as you have it and it only outputs one url. Every post in my wordpress site has a thumbnail so there should be three. Also there is a syntax error that I fixed where thumbnail is mispelled. Will fix in post.

Comment: @C.Ruben many thanks for the feedback and the bug fix. One tend to miss such simple things when coding from mobile devices ;-). I have tested my code, and it works perfectly on my side now. I have updated the last block to include a line break. If you still get only one URL back, you most probably have a bad `pre_get_posts` action somewhere. Add `remove_all_actions( 'pre_get_posts' );` before `$urls = get_latest_post_thumbnails_urls();` and test again. If it works, you need to identify where that bad action is. Do a search through your theme and plugins

Answer (score 1):

**A**) You can store the url in an array. The index of the post currently being displayed is `$current_post`. So you can use it also as array index.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $featureImage[$current_post] = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
    }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

After the Loop you have:

```
$featureImage[0] (value: http://example.org/thumbnail_of_post_1.jpg)

$featureImage[1] (value: http://example.org/thumbnail_of_post_2.jpg)

$featureImage[2] (value: http://example.org/thumbnail_of_post_3.jpg)
```

**B**) You can use multiple queries on a page. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Multiple_Loops) in the Codex.

Comment: Soren, 

Wouldn't that repeatedly set the variable to $featureImage for every wp_get_attachment_url() in the query? How would I get it to something like $featureImage1 $featureImage2, etc. @soren

Regarding the multiple queries, I heard that can cause delay in page load.

Comment: I edited my answer. so you have an better example.

The delay is true, but just a few milliseconds. So you wont recognize it.

Comment: Please see my revised question.